# How to use Angular UI Router With Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Is there a way to use [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) with Node.js, something like [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) or some way to set/inject a window object. I am writing an application that uses Browserify and Jasmine (no Karma) for testing. The `angular-node` NPM module works perfectly in both environments but the `angular-ui-router` and the `angular-router` both fail and I am wondering if there is a solution for this edge case.

Actually I don't need the routes for testing but I have them configured in my Application module and it halts the testing process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe include a routing framework like express.  I use ui-router and node in my projects, mainly I use express for all API calls then all other routes are handled by angular.  You set up the view engine to point to public and put an index.html file which loads ng-app

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.set('view engine', 'html');

Answer (score 0):

i am a big fan of mean.js stack which has a really great implementation of angular including the ui-router on express.

i would recommend checking it out for ideas on how to approach your problem.  the boilerplate gives you plenty to look into.  bower is a great package manager for managing all of your client side dependencies.

sorry this is more or less just some related advice.  i am not very familiar with angular-node which i assume has lead you into this conflict.